# Time complexity of only accessing rows in a matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

while accessing all elements of a matrix we can use to for loops and time complexity is `O(n^2)`. 
But, when we are only accessing rows from a 2D array, what is the time complexity? Is it `O(n)` when n = number of rows?
Ex:-

```
int arr[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
  for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++)
```

The time complexity for the above lines is `O(n^2)`.

But if we access the matrix in the following way will the time complexity still be `O(n^2)` or will it be `O(n)`

```
for (int rows[] : arr) - Time complexity is O(n) or O(n^2)
```

Comment: That loop will only run `rows` times so unless you're doing something complicated within it, it's `O(rows)`. Assuming `rows=cols`, it's `o(n)`

Comment: I feel like closing this as a duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it) You're trying to see something in the code which conflicts with how you calculate big O. The only exception would be a language that makes deep copies of the objects used in for-each loops, which I'm not sure even exists (Java definitely doesn't do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to iterate all cells for each row, so it still be O(n^2).
There is no real difference between those two methods when considering run time.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
  for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++)
```

This is having complexity of O(n) and not O(n^2). That is you are traversing and seeing n items only once and the it linearly increases when n increases.